# OnDeviceChange fires every time it's registered on browser start in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

In Google Chrome 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit) and in MS Edge 108.0.1462.54 (Official build) (64-bit) I'm observing following behavior:

Every time I start the browser (not refresh, no other windows open) and my app registers **ondevicechange** event then it's fired immediately. I don't observe this behavior neither in latest firefox nor in opera. Opening the same code in the new tab doesn't cause this behavior.

Is this behavior by design or is it a bug?
If it's not a bug, is there a way to detect and discard this first call? I don't think writing the logic which detects the browser and skips the first call maintaining the state is a good option. The event object doesn't seem to contain any useful properties to distinguish that.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange = (event) => {
    alert('ON_DEVICE_CHANGE');
};
```

Code to reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/p53utyme/

This behavior was reported by my Frontend developer on his windows 11. It is reproducable every time on my windows 10 computer. Please make sure you have no other instances of chrome or edge running so to reproduce it you need to
a) close all instances of chrome / edge before trying
b) open new instance of chrome / edge with no other tabs
c) open jsfiddle and you should see the alert immediately

It's also reproducable in Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Not reproduced on Win10 + Google Chrome 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: I can't reproduce it on the same version of Edge/Chrome on Win10. Which version of OS do you use?

Comment: @YuZhou I've updated the question, can you please try again?

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I've updated the question, can you please try again?

Comment: I still can't reproduce the issue according to the steps. I suggest that you can [open an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) if it only occurs with chromium in your environment.

Comment: @YuZhou thanks, I've already reproduced it on multiple computers in win 10, 11 and mac  , reported it here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1403403

Comment: The dev from Chromium reproduced it as well and increased the prio from 3 to 2, hope it will be fixed soon :)